# A gwt dropdown ListBox that can have values manually type in?

Tags: gwt

Our GWT based application needs a font size selector.   Ussually people will want to pick the font size from a set of standard sizes.  Sometimes however users will want to manually type in a specific font size like '12.6'.  We obviously cannot put ever tenth of a point option inside our font size dropdown so a dropdown that can have any value entered manually would make the most sense.

I was told simple-gwt has a widget called ComboBox but it appears to be meant for an older version of gwt (we are on the latest - 2.4).  Suggestbox would work except there is no "dropdown" arrow to popup the suggestions so users who do not want to type the size cannot use it.

Any suggestions?  I was surprised this widget was not built into GWT.

Answer (score 1):

The widget to use is the SuggestBox - you may or may not be able to extend it to use a click handler to show a set of default suggestions (there may be a property to allow it) and to use CSS to show a dropdown arrow.

javadoc here: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html

Example here: http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~SuggestBox

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Smart GWT](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category) and [ext-gwt](http://www.extjs.com/examples/) have widgets that provide this kind of functionality, but neither of those libraries are free.

Of course you could always [roll your own](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-4/wiki/DevGuideCreatingCustomWidgets).

Answer (score 0):

I found this library "[Advanced GWT components](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/)".  It is a free library that has drop in GWT widgets.